# Does Kirszbraum's theorem hold for general metric spaces?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request, metric-spaces, lipschitz-functions

On a Chinese online forum, somebody posted a version of  [Kirszbraum's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirszbraun_theorem) without giving a reference for the proof:

> If $(M,d)$ is a metric space, $A\subset M$, $f$ is a real-valued function on $A$ with Lipschitz constant $K$. Then 
>   $$F:M\to \Bbb R,\, x\mapsto \inf_{a\in A}(f(a)+Kd(x,a))$$
>   is a $K$-lipschitz function on $M$ with $F|_A=f$

As I searched on Google,  most versions of this theorem only concern Hilbert spaces. The most generalised one deals with metric spaces with some special structures like "bounded curvature" etc and none of them seems to mention the validity of this theorem for general metric spaces.

So is the above claim true for general metric spaces? If not, is there any obvious counterexample? I myself cannot find one.

Best regards.

Comment: Wikipedia seems to say the answer is yes if the target space is $\Bbb R$; see the last footnote here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity#Properties. The answer seems to be no in general, though counter examples are not easy to come by. Here is a mathoverflow post showing that it can't necessarily be done if $A$ is a continuous curve: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/106388/extension-of-lipschitz-functions-along-a-curve.

Comment: @User8128 well, here The target space *is* R. But there is no restriction on either M or A. So I think your two statements contradict each other.

Comment: In the latter example, the target is no longer $\Bbb R$: $f$ maps a curve in a Banach Space back into that Banach Space ($L^1$ is used as an example).

Comment: @User8128 okay. Here we only care about the case where the range is R. Unfortunately, though, that footnote also comes without a proof. But thanks anyway for the source. I'm confident in the validity of Wikipedia.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. The answer to your question is yes (according to Wikipedia). However, if you have a Lipschitz map $f:A \to Y$ where $Y$ is some other Metric space, it seems you can not generally extend $f$ to a Lipschitz map $F: M \to Y$ with the same Lipschitz constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't know this was a theorem, but it is a standard exercise in real analysis: Let $x, y \in M$. Then for every $a\in A$, 
\begin{eqnarray}
F(x)&\leq& f(a)+Kd(x, a) \\
&\leq & f(a)+Kd(y,a)+ Kd(x, y). 
\end{eqnarray}

By taking infimum, we have $F(x)\leq F(y)+Kd(x,y)$.

Answer (score 3):

As tree detective pointed out, this is a relatively simple fact. It is sometimes called McShane's theorem or the McShane-Whitney extension theorem. (For example, see in Heinonen's book *Lectures on Analysis on Metric Spaces*.)

I would hesitate to call it a version of Kirszbraun's theorem. Kirszbraun's theorem applies to Hilbert space targets of arbitrary dimension (but only Hilbert space domain). McShane's theorem applies to $\mathbb{R}$ target but arbitrary metric domain. The proofs are correspondingly quite different.

Note that also McShane's theorem implies that if $X$ is a metric space, $E\subset X$, and $f:E\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is $K$-Lipschitz, then $f$ has an extension to a function on $X$ which is $K\sqrt{n}$-Lipschitz. (Apply McShane's theorem to each component of $f$.)

However, you can't preserve the Lipschitz constant of the extension for maps from general metric spaces to $\mathbb{R}^n$ targets.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.