# Continuous extension of a function which retains the modulus of continuity

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

#### Question

Let $S \subset \mathbb R^d$ be compact and $f : S \to \mathbb R$ be continuous (hence uniformly continuous) on $S$. A function $\omega : (0,\infty) \to (0,\infty)$ is called a modulus of continuity for $f$ if, for all $\epsilon>0$,$$
\|x-y\| < \omega(\epsilon) \implies |f(x)-f(y)| < \epsilon, \text{for all } x,y \in S.
$$
In other words, $\delta = \omega(\epsilon)$ satisfies the $\epsilon-\delta$ of uniform continuity for $f$. Furthermore, as illustrated by a counterexample in the comments, we *insist* that $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \omega(\epsilon) =0$.

> Suppose that $S \subset \mathbb R^d$ is compact and $f : S \to \mathbb R$ admits a modulus of continuity $\omega$ on $S$. Does there exist a function $g : \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R$ such that (a) $g(x) = f(x)$ on $S$, and (b) $g$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R^d$ with modulus of continuity $\omega$? We can possibly relax the modulus of continuity of $g$ to be of the form $C \times \omega$ for any $C>0$ positive, but not more than that.

---

#### Motivation

In order to motivate this question, it helps to look at other extension theorems.

- Given $f : O \to \mathbb R$ uniformly continuous on an open set $O$, it admits a unique extension to $\overline{O}$ which is also uniformly continuous. The proof technique is to define $\tilde{f}(x) = \lim_{y \to x, y \in O} f(y)$ and show that this works.
- Given any $f : S \to \mathbb R$ continuous where $S$ is closed, it admits a continuous extension to $\mathbb R^d$. This follows directly from the Tietze extension theorem.
- If we assume that the modulus of continuity has a *specific* structure, then some results are known. See e.g. the [Kirszbraun Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirszbraun_theorem) for Lipschitz moduli of continuity i.e. $\omega(\epsilon) = C\epsilon$ for some $C>0$. Here's a [nice proof](https://www1.essex.ac.uk/maths/people/fremlin/n11706.pdf) of that result.

---

What makes this particularly difficult to approach is the control of the modulus of continuity of $g$ outside the set $S$. For example, suppose that we naively try to force $g$ to be constant outside an open set $O$ which contains $S$, so that its modulus of continuity is controlled on $O^c$. Certainly we can find a function $g$ such that $g \equiv f$ on $S$ and $g \equiv 0$ on $O$, by a variation of Tietze's theorem. However, what we can't do using that scheme is control $|g(x)-g(y)|$ in the region between $S$ and $O$. That's what makes this question interesting.

Comment: See [*Extension of range of functions*](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1934-40-12/S0002-9904-1934-05978-0/) by Edward James McShane (1934). **Related:** [Extending Holder functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4701780/13130) (MSE) AND [Extending Hölder functions](https://mathoverflow.net/q/447301/15780) (mathoverflow) AND [McShane's theorem for Euclidean spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4385114/13130) (MSE) AND [Does Kirszbraum's theorem hold for general metric spaces?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2312396/13130) (MSE).

Comment: Consider $S=[0,1]\cup[3,4]$ and $f(x)=\boldsymbol{1}_{[0,1]}(x)$. Then you can choose $\omega(\epsilon)\equiv 1$, whereas $\omega(\epsilon)\to 0$ for a continuous extension over $[0,4]$.

Comment: @WillowWisp Excellent, that works. Maybe I should restrict myself to moduli of continuity that "go to zero" in that $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \omega(\epsilon) = 0$. Certainly every uniformly continuous function admits such a modulus of continuity, including the one you mention (take $\omega(\epsilon) = \epsilon \wedge 1$). I'll edit the assumptions to reflect this.